# How to make sync between multiple devices of a same user using ObjectBox Sync?

Tags: objectbox, flutter-objectbox

I know ObjectBox Sync is able to sync data across multiple devices, my question is that:

How to make synchronization between multiple devices belongs to the same user?
You know in my use case, our app is an Internet app serving many users around the world, how to sync between the devices belongs to the same user.

For example, if there is an A user who has two devices, D1 and D2. B is another user who has another two devices, D3 and D4.

We just want to sync data between D1 and D2 for the user A, whereas sync data between D3 and D4 for the user B.

Comment: We are aware of the importance of user specific data spaces. It will be our top priority once we finish some ongoing work in an enterprise context. Data spaces are planned later for this year.